# Externalize properties in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi

I would like to configure a series of environment-dependant settings as an external resource, so that the same WAR artifact can be configured in any application server.

In Glassfish I rememeber that I just created a .properties file using the built-in Properties Resource JNDI Factory, and it worked like a charm, but there's no such thing in Tomcat.

I tried defining a java.net.URL and a java.lang.String to define just the path that this file is held in, but I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/c://app.properties]
```

So what would be a good way to create an environment-agnostic set of properties for my application?

PS: this is how I define my properties in Spring:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="appProperties" jndi-name="java:comp/env/url/urlAppProperties" />

        <bean id="application-properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
            <property name="locations">
                <list>
                    <value>#{ appProperties }</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add external configuration values to the JNDI context using Tomcat's resource configuration elements. As described in the [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/globalresources.html), you can define a `<GlobalNamingResources>` element in your `server.xml` listing a set of configuration values which are available to all contexts (web applications) on that server:

Example taken from the Tomcat docs:

```
<GlobalNamingResources ...>
  ...
  <Environment name="maxExemptions" value="10"
         type="java.lang.Integer" override="false"/>
  ...
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

These environment variables are then available via JDNI in the `java:comp/env` context. In order to use such variables in a web application, you have to link to them in the individual `context.xml` configuration files using the `<ResourceLink>` element.

```
<Context>
    <ResourceLink name="maxExemptions" global="maxExemptions" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
</Context>
```

With this set up, you can access these values through the standard JNDI API.